# How to create a link with ApachePOI?

Tags: spring, apache-poi

I want to set the data inside a cell to be a link :

```
public class TestExcelExport extends AbstractXlsxView {

    @Override
    protected void buildExcelDocument(Map<String, Object> model, Workbook workbook, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {

        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"export.xlsx\"");

        Sheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("test");

        Row row_1 = sheet.createRow(1);

        row_1.createCell(0).setCellValue("some data");

    }

}
```

How to make the cell data to be a link pointing to a file in the system directory ?

Comment: https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#How+to+create+hyperlinks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CreationHelper createHelper = workbook.getCreationHelper();
Cell cell = row_1.createCell((short)0);
cell.setCellValue("System File Link");
link = createHelper.createHyperlink(Hyperlink.LINK_FILE);
link.setAddress("/usr/somedir/somefile.someext");
cell.setHyperlink(link);
```

This would do.